# How to make a color digital clock that updates the background color by using the time as the rgb values?

Tags: java, swing

I want to make a digital clock with a background color that changes each time the clock ticks. The color is based on the time (using the time as the rgb values). I have tried the following, the clock itself works, but the background color does not work as intended.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class SimpleDigitalClock {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame f = new JFrame();

    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    DigitalClock myClock = new DigitalClock();
    f.add(myClock);
    f.setBackground(new Color(myClock.getHour(), myClock.getMinute(), myClock.getSecond()));
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

static class DigitalClock extends JPanel {

    String stringTime;
    int hour, minute, second;

    String correctionHour = "";
    String correctionMinute = "";
    String correctionSecond = "";

    public int getHour(){
      return hour;
    }

    public int getMinute(){
      return minute;
    }

    public int getSecond(){
      return second;
    }

    public void setStringTime(String xyz) {
        this.stringTime = xyz;
    }

    public int findMinimumBetweenTwoNumbers(int a, int b) {
        return (a <= b) ? a : b;
    }

    DigitalClock() {
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(); 
        p1.setOpaque(true);
        p1.setBackground(new Color(hour, minute, second));
        add(p1);
        Timer t1 = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                repaint();
            }
        });
        t1.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        second = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        if (hour < 10) {
            this.correctionHour = "0";
        }
        if (hour >= 10) {
            this.correctionHour = "";
        }

        if (minute < 10) {
            this.correctionMinute = "0";
        }
        if (minute >= 10) {
            this.correctionMinute = "";
        }

        if (second < 10) {
            this.correctionSecond = "0";
        }
        if (second >= 10) {
            this.correctionSecond = "";
        }
        setStringTime(correctionHour + hour + ":" + correctionMinute+ minute + ":" + correctionSecond + second);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        int length = findMinimumBetweenTwoNumbers(this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());
        Font myFont = new Font("Digital", Font.PLAIN, length / 5);
        g.setFont(myFont);
        g.drawString(stringTime, (int) length/6, length/2);

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Then how is the background color intended to look?

Comment: You need to translate the values. Color chanels can be from 0 to 255 but hour only from 1to 24. You won' t see much difference. You have to add a factor so 1-24 is translated to values 0-255. Same for minute and second. I dont see where you set bg color in your paint method neither.

Comment: I was intending it to look something like this: http://thecolourclock.co.uk/ this one uses the time as hex values. Any ideas on how to turn time into hex values?

Comment: Is your question about converting time to hex or about Swing GUI? Decide which it is.

Comment: Converting time to hex and displaying the background color using hex

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

> Converting time to hex

The conversion of 24-hour-based time to hex is not unique. A simple way to do it would be to stretch the 24 hour, 60 minute and 60 second spaces to a 256 space each:

```
hexHour = hour * 256 / 24 = hour * 10 2/3
hexMinute = minute * 256 / 60 = minute * 4 4/15
hexSecond = second * 256 / 60 = second * 4 4/15
```

There will be small corrections needed if you want to cover the whole RGB space since in this convention you skip values as seen above. Instead of jumping in the Red space by 10 2/3 every hour, you can jump by 1 every 5 5/8 minutes:

```
60 / (10 2/3) = 5 5/8
```

And similarly for the other spaces.

> and displaying the background color using hex.

As for setting the background color, just use `setBackground` on your clock. Here I use a very simplistic GUI with 3 `JLabel`s for the hours, minutes and seconds:

```
public class ColorClock extends JFrame {

    ColorClock() {

        JLabel minutes = new JLabel();
        JLabel seconds = new JLabel();
        JLabel hours = new JLabel();

        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
                int hour = time.getHour();
                int min = time.getMinute();
                int sec = time.getSecond();
                hours.setText(String.valueOf(hour));
                minutes.setText(":" + String.valueOf(min + ":"));
                seconds.setText(String.valueOf(sec));
                Color color = new Color(hour * 256 / 24, min * 256 / 60, sec * 256 / 60);
                getContentPane().setBackground(color);
            }
        }, 0, 1000);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(hours);
        add(minutes);
        add(seconds);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {

        new ColorClock();
    }
}
```

Do note that the code is not optimized in any way and is not thread safe, it's just for the demonstration of changing the color (`swing.Timer` is more correct here than `util.Timer`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to make the clock.

[image: Clock]

The code to change the color of the Border is in the Clock class setBackground method.  I just used the minutes and seconds to make the border color change faster.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Clock implements Runnable {

    private JFrame frame;

    private JPanel panel;

    private JTextField clockDisplay;

    private Timer timer;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Clock");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                exitProcedure();
            }
        });

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 6));

        clockDisplay = new JTextField(12);
        clockDisplay.setEditable(false);
        clockDisplay.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

        panel.add(clockDisplay);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        timer = new Timer(this);
        new Thread(timer).start();
    }

    public void exitProcedure() {
        timer.setRunning(false);
        frame.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        clockDisplay.setText(text);
    }

    public void setBackground(Calendar calendar) {
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        hour = hour * 255 / 24;
        minute = minute * 255 / 60;
        second = second * 255 / 60;

        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(second,
                minute, second), 6));
        panel.validate();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Clock());
    }

    public class Timer implements Runnable {

        private volatile boolean running;

        private Clock clock;

        private SimpleDateFormat timeFormat;

        public Timer(Clock clock) {
            this.clock = clock;
            this.running = true;
            this.timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm:ss a");
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                displayTime();
                sleep();
            }

        }

        public void displayTime() {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date date = calendar.getTime();
            final String s = timeFormat.format(date);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    clock.setText(s);
                    clock.setBackground(calendar);
                }
            });
        }

        public void sleep() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

        public synchronized void setRunning(boolean running) {
            this.running = running;
        }

    }

}
```